# ionic iframe url bar somehow visible, hide it

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, iframe, capacitor, huawei-developers

I build an app in ionic witch capacitor not cordova. This app work well every device, instead Huawei p30 pro. In app there is a page which show an iframe element. The iframe url bar is visible, but I would like to hide it. This problem is only Huawei P30 Pro device seen. How can I hide it?
[image]

Comment: HI@Bálint Bakos,To trace this issue, Could you pls send your apk to hmscore@huawei.com?

Comment: Dear, @shirley you can download app in this link:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=brimme.app

Comment: sorry@Bálint Bakos,seem like i can't download it through this link  :( it shows"
This item cannot be installed in your device's country " so could you pls provide your apk to us to check this issue?

Comment: Dear, @shirley i enebled China region too.

Comment: Just confirmed,seems like still cannot download this app in China :( shows the same prompt as above.

Comment: @shirley I added all of the countries :D if it not work, I'm clueless

Comment: hi@Bálint Bakos,I downloaded it and after testing, the iframe url bar will be displayed when choose to log in though the Google Chrome browser,and if you don't choose Google Chrome to log in,the iframe url bar will not be displayed.The reason why the iframe url bar is visible,This may be because the procedure after the Google browser login is completed on the browser.https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EueYQqFUUAI6y5K?format=jpg&name=4096x4096 You are advised to check the link after logging in to the web browser.